# Reading in data to a bubble sort algorithm in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

My code snippet:

```
# BubbleSort in Python 3

def bubblesort(mylist):
    for i in range (0, len(mylist) - 1): 
        for j in range (0 , len(mylist) - 1 - i):
            if mylist[j] > mylist[j+1]:
                mylist[j], mylist[j+1] = mylist[j+1], mylist[j]
    return mylist

thelist = ['4','5','4','3','7','6','9','0']
print(bubblesort(thelist))
```

The File `numbers.txt`contains data:

> 2
>   5
>   32
>   6
>   4
>   7
>   9
>   8
>   6
>   34
>   1343
>   5
>   5343

I am trying to read in these numbers from this text file into the variable `thelist`. What code do I need to change/write to make this happen?

Comment: This code isn't valid Python. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

**This code will read from file, then sort and then save to file. and print the sorted list**

```
def bubblesort(mylist):
    for i in range (0, len(mylist) - 1): 
        for j in range (0 , len(mylist) - 1 - i):
            if mylist[j] > mylist[j+1]:
                mylist[j], mylist[j+1] = mylist[j+1], mylist[j]
    return mylist

def read():
    #read from file
    f = open("numbers.txt","r")
    data = f.read().split()# convert string to list by split
    f.close()
    # for each element in list convert to int
    for i in range(len(data)):
        data[i] = int(data[i])
    return data

def write(thelist):
    #create edit the text file
    file = open("numbers.txt", "wt")
    # for each element in list write i value and add space between new value
    for i in range(len(thelist)):
        file.write(str(thelist[i]) + " ")
    file.close()

thelist = read()
print(bubblesort(thelist))
write(thelist)
```